# Getting color of pixel from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found a lot of examples showing how to get a color of pixel at certain point of image.
Basically all of them looks similar. For example:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('something'); 
context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var pixel = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
console.log(pixel[0] + ' ' + pixel[1] + ' ' + pixel[2]);
```

However, when I'm executing code shown above it always gives me the same results: "0 0 0 0" or "0 0 0 255", regardless what is an actual color of image.
I tried it on different colors and output is always the same.
Can someone please explain my why this happening?
Why only value of alpha is changing? (and why it's always only 0 or 255)
Maybe should I cast results somehow or I'm not getting them correctly?

Comment: To answer your question we'll need to see how your canvas is defined and how you're putting image data on it in the first place, ideally in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What values have the `x` and `y` variables? Maybe are both undefined and it returns an inexistent pixel.

Comment: Note that you are not able to do "getImageData()" on a image loaded from another domain due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. However, there would an exception normally.

Comment: In my code, content of canvas isn't loaded from image. It's drawn by script loaded from the same location as other scripts.
`x` and `y` values are Integer values from loop (I'm sure that those values are correct).

Here is an example posted by someone in another discussion: http://jsbin.com/wepuca/2/edit?html,js,console,output

It acts exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example jsbin you've linked to](http://jsbin.com/wepuca/2/edit?html,js,console,output) in the comments works fine (other than a `e.pageX` where it should be `e.pageY`, but that's not changing the outcome), the issue here is the actual expected outcome.

Where it's been drawn on in black, you get `0 0 0 255` (ie opaque black).  Where it's not been drawn on (and is therefore red), you're getting `0 0 0 0` which is "default values (0)" and *transparent*, which is why you're seeing the background red colour show through.  There's nothing actually *on* the canvas at that point - it's transparent.

Here's an updated example where the canvas is split into 4.  The first 3 columns show differing outputs, whereas the last one is `0 0 0 0` due to the canvas not being drawn on at that point - the background colour is *not part of the image data* for the canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 75, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(75, 0, 75, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(150, 0, 75, 150);


function echoColor(e){
  
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1);
 red = imgData.data[0];
 green = imgData.data[1];
 blue = imgData.data[2];
 alpha = imgData.data[3];
 console.log(red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha); 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="background:red;" onclick="echoColor(event)">
</canvas>
```

Comment: So background-color isn't treated as part of canvas. Now it's seems so obvious. Thanks!